# How to turn integer in document into a variable

Tags: python

The bingo.config has a string with a random integer in it.
Inside the file, it looks like

```
boothNumber="2"
```

My template.config file has the same string with a different integer or number.
I am trying to replace this with the current integer in bingo.config

My problem is that the number in template.config is not being replaced by the number in bingo.config

It's replacing the number in template.config with the literal string "r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'"

So template.config ends up looking like

```
boothNumber="r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'"
```

instead of

```
boothNumber="2"
```

It looks like my issue is stemming from how I save the variable "pattern" in the "readconfig" function.

Any ideas on how I can save the integer from bingo.config into a proper variable that can be used?

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import re  # used to replace string
import sys # prevents extra lines being inputed in config
           # example: sys.stdout.write


def convertconfig(pattern):                        
    source = "template.config"
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            match = r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'
            sys.stdout.write(re.sub(match, pattern, line))


def readconfig():
    source = "bingo.config"
    pattern = r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'  # !!!!!!!!!! This probably needs fixed
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                fileinput.close()
                convertconfig(pattern)

def copyfrom(servername):

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/remotedirectory'
    dest = r"C:/myprogram"
    file = "bingo.config"
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))

    except:
        print ("Error")

    readconfig()


# begin here
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        copyfrom(servername.strip())
```

Comment: So you are looking to read the config and change any variables in your current document that do not match to the values found in the config file? If that's right what about dictionaries?

Comment: I want to use function 'readconfig' to get a string and a number out of bingo.config.  Then save that info to 'pattern'.  Then replace the same string and different number in template.config with 'pattern'.